# Javascript path issue I think?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, relative-path

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../../Content/CSS/lavalamp.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

    <title>DatsWussup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="lavaLampWithImage">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $(".lavaLampWithImage").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 }) });
</script>

</html>
```

So that's my master page. This is my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/DatsWussup.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

I included all the lavalamp plugin files in my project, and there are located in the Scripts/ and Content/ folders, which are both two layers above the master page file.

What am I doing wrong? The page comes up completely blank.

The firebug 'Net' tab says it's loading the CSS and jquery-1.4.1.js file fine, but not the others, and it's also supposed to be pulling down some images that are referenced in the CSS file as well like this:

```
url("../Images/bg.gif")
```

Where the Images/ and CSS/ folders are on the same layer.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags should not be self closed, you should write out `<script></script>` instead of `<script />`